# Servicio de geolocalzacion en android no se ejecuta en segundo plano

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gps, http-post

estoy haciendo una aplicación que me mande las coordenadas a un servidor PHP por POST, en primer lugar lo intente hacer para que se ejecutara cada x tiempo con un handler, pero no he conseguido que se ejecute en los intervalos que definí,(no se si es porque se pone en modo ahorro de energía o el
GPS inactivo ...) y viendo que de esta manera no me funcionó, le he intentado usando el onLocationchange del LocationListener, pero al cerrar la aplicación muere el proceso y yo necesito que se siga ejecutando en segundo plano siempre hasta que yo pare el servicio manuelmente.

Adjunto ambos códigos.

Este es el que se ejecuta con el onlocationChange

```
 package com.androidmorefast.pc.appguardargpsbd;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;


public class ServicesGeolocation extends Service implements LocationListener {
    MainActivity mainActivity;
    public MainActivity getMainActivity() {
        return mainActivity;
    }
    public void setMainActivity(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    double speed;
    String direccion;
    Location location;
    private Context thisContent = this;
    private String url;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();


    }
public void getLocation(){
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

    }
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 1000, this);
}


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ejecutar();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    private void ejecutar() {
        Handler h = new Handler(Looper.myLooper());
        h.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                getLocation();
                metodoEjecutar();
            }
        });
    }

    private void metodoEjecutar(){
        //new Insertar(getApplicationContext(ServicesGeolocation.this)).execute();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                insertar();
                Looper.loop();

            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(thisContent, "Servicio Detenido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       location.getLatitude();
       location.getLongitude();
       location.getSpeed();

        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        speed=location.getSpeed();
        if (latitude != 0.0 && longitude != 0.0) {
            try {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                        latitude, longitude, 1);
                if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                    Address DirCalle = list.get(0);
                    direccion=DirCalle.getAddressLine(0);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        switch (status) {
            case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.AVAILABLE");
                break;
            case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE");
                break;
            case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(thisContent, "GPS Desactivado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(thisContent, "GPS Desactivado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    private boolean insertar() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            speed=location.getSpeed();
        }
        if (latitude != 0.0 && longitude != 0.0) {
            try {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                        latitude, longitude, 1);
                if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                    Address DirCalle = list.get(0);
                    direccion=DirCalle.getAddressLine(0);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //Log.d("TAG", direccion);
        SharedPreferences sh
                = getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref",
                MODE_PRIVATE);

        String s1 = sh.getString("mail", "");
        double kmsPorHora = speed * 3.6;

        HttpClient httpClient;
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
        HttpPost httpPost;
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpPost = new HttpPost("https://gda360.gonzalezdeautomocion.com/insertar.php");//url del servidor
        //empezamos añadir nuestros datos
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("coordenadas",  String.valueOf(latitude)+","+String.valueOf(longitude)));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("velocidad",String.valueOf(kmsPorHora)));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("direccion",direccion));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",s1));
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF_8"));
            httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            return true;


        } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (ClientProtocolException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  false;

    }


}
```

y este es el que hize para que se ejecutase cada x tiempo que tampoco me funciona del todo bien porque no siempre se ejecuta

```
package com.androidmorefast.pc.appguardargpsbd;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;


public class ServicesGeolocation extends Service implements LocationListener {
    MainActivity mainActivity;
    public MainActivity getMainActivity() {
        return mainActivity;
    }
    public void setMainActivity(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    double speed;
    String direccion;
    Location location;
    private Context thisContent = this;
    private String url;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();


    }
public void getLocation(){
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

    }
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 100, this);
}


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getLocation();
        // ejecutar();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void ejecutar() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getLocation();
                metodoEjecutar();//llamamos nuestro metodo
                handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);//se ejecutara cada 10 segundos
            }
        }, 5);//empezara a ejecutarse después de 5 milisegundos
    }

    private void metodoEjecutar() {
        //new Insertar(getApplicationContext(ServicesGeolocation.this)).execute();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                   // insertar();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(thisContent, "Servicio Detenido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(location));
       location.getLatitude();
       location.getLongitude();
       location.getSpeed();

        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        speed=location.getSpeed();
        if (latitude != 0.0 && longitude != 0.0) {
            try {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                        latitude, longitude, 1);
                if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                    Address DirCalle = list.get(0);
                    direccion=DirCalle.getAddressLine(0);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            speed=location.getSpeed();
        }
        if (latitude != 0.0 && longitude != 0.0) {
            try {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                        latitude, longitude, 1);
                if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                    Address DirCalle = list.get(0);
                    direccion=DirCalle.getAddressLine(0);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        SharedPreferences sh
                = getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref",
                MODE_PRIVATE);

        String s1 = sh.getString("mail", "");
        double kmsPorHora = speed * 3.6;

        HttpClient httpClient;
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
        HttpPost httpPost;
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpPost = new HttpPost("https://gda360.gonzalezdeautomocion.com/insertar.php");//url del servidor
        //empezamos añadir nuestros datos
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("coordenadas",  String.valueOf(latitude)+","+String.valueOf(longitude)));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("velocidad",String.valueOf(kmsPorHora)));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("direccion",direccion));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",s1));
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF_8"));
            httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (ClientProtocolException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        switch (status) {
            case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.AVAILABLE");
                break;
            case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE");
                break;
            case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(thisContent, "GPS Desactivado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(thisContent, "GPS Desactivado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }





}
```

Ninguno de los dós códigos consigo que funcione bien pero realmente el que a mi me interesa es que se ejecute cuando cambie la localización y funcione en segundo plano aun que cierre la aplicación.

[image: captura del servicio corriendo 100%]

Muchisimas gracias con antelación
Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que te diría es que en una parte de tu código denotas esto:

```
handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);//se ejecutara cada 10 segundos
```

Y en realidad eso no hace que se ejecute cada 10 segundos tu tarea, **sino 10 segundos después y por una sola ocasión**.
Posteriormente, mencionas que a veces funciona, y a veces no... y lo que veo en esta parte de tu código:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 100, this);
```

Es que indicas que te realice actualizaciones de la geolocalizacion, sí lo mas pronto posible, pero si hay diferencia de al menos 100 metros entre la ubicación actual y la nueva, y tal vez por eso no te anda ningún cambio porque supongo pruebas esa información sin moverte demasiado.. Te pongo unas líneas que denotan lo que te acabo de mencionar:

```
        //Minimo tiempo para updates en Milisegundos
    private static final long MIN_TIEMPO_ENTRE_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minuto
    //Minima distancia para updates en metros.
    private static final long MIN_CAMBIO_DISTANCIA_PARA_UPDATES = 1.5; // 1.5 metros

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
            MIN_TIEMPO_ENTRE_UPDATES, MIN_CAMBIO_DISTANCIA_PARA_UPDATES, locListener,
            this);
```

Por último, para que garantices que tus servicios siempre se ejecuten en segundo plano aunque se cierre la app, es correcto hacerlo con un **Service**, sin embargo yo le añadiría un **ForegroundService**, un ejemplo sería el siguiente:

**En tu Service**

```
    private void requestForegroundNoti(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        startMyOwnForeground();
    }else{
        // Se construye la notificación (Android Viejos)
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_dialer)
                .setContentTitle("MONITOR Activo")
                .setContentText("Monitoreando valores de fit band B8");
        startForeground(1, builder.build());
    }
}

private void startMyOwnForeground(){
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.gh.b2w.monitorIA";
    String channelName = "BLE CT Service";
    NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
    chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
    chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    assert manager != null;
    manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_watch_24)
            .setColor(Color.BLUE)
            .setContentTitle("MONITOR IA Activo")
            .setContentText("Monitoreando valores de fit band B8")
            .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .build();
    startForeground(2, notification);
}
```

**Y en tu manifest.xml**

```
        <service
        android:foregroundServiceType="location"
        android:name=".Services.MonitoringKodakService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
```

Cabe señalar que esto te creara una notificación inmediatamente después de abandonar la app, la cual no se puede eliminar a menos que el usuario vaya al apartado de configuraciones y lo haga manualmente
Intenta realizar esas modificaciones y tal vez ya funcione correctamente.

Espero te sirva!